# Ask turtle to move to a specific coordinate

Tags: netlogo

I have a scenario in which I want turtles to move toward a specific location. Not just jump to the location but like a normal walk toward a specific location(Coordinate)?

Comment: check out Move Towards Target Example, in the Code Examples section of the Models Library

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the models library and the Netlogo dictionary and some basic Netlogo tutorials.

However, if your coordinate is a patch or a turtle, you can use the face command which will set the heading to face the target. You could then move forward by using the forward command `fd`. If your coordinate was an x and y, you could use `facexy`

```
ask turtles 
[
   face target
   fd speed
]
```